# Delayed start of GIF image in IE & Edge

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, microsoft-edge, gif

I am trying to showing a spinning image on my website. I have tried it quite simply like below in HTML -

```
<div id="wait" style="display:none;width:300px;height:300px;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;padding:2px;">
<img src='image/spinner.gif' width="300" height="300" />
</div>
```

And just changing its display property from Jquery like below -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#example").on("click", "tbody tr td:nth-child(3)", function() {
            **$("#wait").css("display", "block");**
            var $name = $(this).text();
            var $name2 = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();
            var $name3 = $name.concat("&&val=", $name2);
            var uid = getUrlVars()["uid"];
            var fid = getUrlVars()["fid"];
            var url1 = 'logapi1.php?query=' + $name + '&&val=' + $name2;
            var url2 = 'logapi2.php?query=' + $name + '&&val=' + $name2;
            var url3 = 'logapiheader.php?query=' + $name + '&&val=' + $name2;
            var url4 = 'logapifull.php?query=' + $name + '&&val=' + $name2;
            var url5 = 'logapinum.php?query=' + $name + '&&val=' + $name2;
            var urls = [url1, url2, url3, url4, url5];
            console.log(urls);
            $.each(urls, function(i, u) {
                $.ajax(u, {
                    type: "POST",
                    datatype: "JSON",
                    async: false,
                    success: function() {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            });
            window.location = "logpage02.php?query=" + $name3 + "&&uid=" + uid + "&&fid=" + fid;
        });
        </script>
```

This is working in IE11, Edge & Firefox.

But problem is that, in FF, Gif started immediately after clicking on the td link. Whereas in IE & Edge, its getting started after few ms. For example, for 2secs delay, in FF gif started immediately after clicking the link and staying for 2secs. But for IE & Edge, its starting almost after 1sec and staying for 1sec.

**I know this is not a big issue, still want to know why this is happening.**

Comment: I suggest you try to test with Async: true. Check whether it can help to fix the issue. It looks like when requests are getting executes then execution of gif gets stopped. This can be a possible cause of this issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT But will that be different in different browsers? In FF it is working perfectly. In IE & Edge also it is working, just a few ms delyed starting, then working fine.

Comment: I think that in those few milliseconds your requests get executed and then GIF starts working. Every browser uses a different browser engine. It depends on that browser engine. So output can vary browser to browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run the code you showed. I found that there was no motion delay at IE, Edge, and Google.You could check if there is a problem with your spinning image.

You could refer to the following methods for more information.

1. The impact of Edge's [Lazy Loading](https://geekermag.com/enable-lazy-image-loading-in-edge-browser/) feature.
2. Disable [third-party add-ons](https://www.dummies.com/computers/pcs/how-to-manage-add-ons-in-internet-explorer/) to relieve the delay.